# OpenProcess failed to open existing process via id (Last Error code: 1008)?

Tags: c#, winapi, process, pinvoke

I'm trying to use `OpenProcess` to open all existing processes via the process ID. But somehow it works just the first call, while the next calls show that it does not work with an error code reported as `1008` (*An attempt was made to reference a token that does not exist*).

Here is the code:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags access, bool inheritHandle, int procId);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

[Flags]
public enum ProcessAccessFlags : uint
{
    All = 0x001F0FFF,
    Terminate = 0x00000001,
    CreateThread = 0x00000002,
    VirtualMemoryOperation = 0x00000008,
    VirtualMemoryRead = 0x00000010,
    VirtualMemoryWrite = 0x00000020,
    DuplicateHandle = 0x00000040,
    CreateProcess = 0x000000080,
    SetQuota = 0x00000100,
    SetInformation = 0x00000200,
    QueryInformation = 0x00000400,
    QueryLimitedInformation = 0x00001000,
    Synchronize = 0x00100000
}

foreach (var proc in Process.GetProcesses()) {
    var procHandle = OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags.QueryInformation | ProcessAccessFlags.VirtualMemoryOperation, false, proc.Id);
    var eCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(); 
    //checking the last error code using Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() 
    //shows that it succeeds the first time with error code of 0
    //Then all the next calls show error code of `1008`.
    if(procHandle != IntPtr.Zero) CloseHandle(procHandle);
}
```

I've tried googling for the error but not sure what could be wrong here. It would be nice if you can let me know what's wrong. Thank you!

**UPDATE:**
As I said it seems to work just for the first process in the loop. BUT I highly doubt that it actually does not work even for that case because from what I see the `procHandle` keeping a totally different value from the `proc.Handle`, ***unless*** the handle returned by `OpenProcess` is *another kind* of handle and not the same to `proc.Handle` (if so it's really weird). So if what I'm currently doubting is true, that means `OpenProcess` totally does not work at all. It's simply useless in this case and still not sure in which context we can use it.

Comment: This seems perfectly normal. You have two different PIDs. Not surprising that you can do things with one, but not the other. FWIW, you do not have an `hwnd`. That would be a handle to a window. `OpenProcess` returns a process handle. Quite a different beast.

Comment: If you look at `proc.ProcessName` what process is it failing on?  If that property doesn't give any information, does the PID correspond to a valid process on your system?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't understand your explanation. You said `OpenProcess` returns a process handle and I obviously set `hwnd` to the return value. So why did you also say `hwnd` would be a handle to a window?

Comment: @theB the foreach loop works OK and I can see that different process comes in its turn. As I explained, it failed right at the second process. The `ProcessName` is not important in this case.

Comment: The process name is not important except that it could help you locate the error, if it refers to an invalid process, or one which you have no rights to access, or a process that recently terminated, or any number of other things... Also, `GetLastError` only contains an extended error something if the returned handle is `NULL` (aka `IntPtr.Zero`).  Is the returned handle NULL?

Comment: @theB I don't think it would be failed for all processes in the list of about 138 processes (both 32 and 64 bit) currently on my machine except just the first one (in the loop) and I've done that for many F5 and it is still the same. The failure here is not thrown in exception so the code should work for at least some ones it can read the info no matter when  they come in the loop. I've just tried even re-ordering the processes by `ProcessName` and it still shows the same result (failed from the second). The return value of `OpenProcess` is `0` only in 2-3 last loops and almost 1 same value.

Comment: @theB and if possible, please try my code on your side to understand it more. I don't think it should work on your side. The code is just simple as you see, no other code is required.

Comment: hwnd is a variable name used to hold a handle to a window

Comment: @DavidHeffernan do you mean `OpenProcess` will put some Window's handle to it? I don't think the name matters here. Still don't understand what's going on? Should I need to name it differently?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan you may talk about naming convention here. But I just forgot what `hwnd` stands for (handle of window) in a moment. So that does not mean I want a window handle in this case.

Comment: How about an [mcve] so that we can see a specific process that cannot be opened

Comment: @DavidHeffernan have you even tried running my code yet? isn't that not short enough? If you read all my comments above, you'll see I just talked about that problem. No specific process is involved here. Only the first process in the loop (no matter the order is) has `GetLastWin32Error` return `0` (although I'm not sure if that means it succeeds). All the other calls come with `1008` and some are `6`, ... I think your question means my problem is unable to be reproduced on your side. If so please let me know.

Comment: Your code doesn't call GetLastWin32Error.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I did not think that is so important for you to test my code. I talked about using `GetLastWin32Error` so almost every one here understanding about Win32 should know where to use it in code in this case, it's just a way to test if everything is just fine and you should of course know how to use it. If you really wanted to run the code, test it, check it, you should not have to add much your own code to my code. I'm now not sure if you're really interested in this problem. If so just leave it off. I don't really hope someone could answer this.

Comment: I'd be interested if I knew I was running the same code as you. But you didn't post the real code. I know what I'm doing. Post an [mcve] and you'll get help. Make us guess, and there will be indifference.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan that's the real code. The difference is just before it missed `GetLastWin32Error`, can that really possibly make a difference in result? And finally now I added that line, it's now my real code. I currently have a project with just that code. No big project as you might imagine. I guess you may even want me to add some `using` namespace statements, or even the main class constructor? I've helped some other users in SO BUT I've never required them to do so, it's so trivial indeed. You may just want to copy & paste & run, so you 99% cannot help.

Comment: Well, the latest edit shows that your error checking is wrong. That's why I wanted an [mcve]. I've done this before. These things matter.

Comment: Expect `proc.Handle` to be a different numeric value from that returned by `OpenProcess`.

Comment: @Hopeless I did run your example.  I had to guess as to what the error check looked like.  (Incidentally, the version I used looks remarkably like the answer below.)  So far, we know that it's failing, but we have no idea what process you're trying to open that's causing the failure. If you're _never_ getting zero returned, then there's a bigger problem, because there are a handful of processes on every system that you cannot open with this method.

Comment: To expand a bit on @DavidHeffernan's comment:  `CreateProcess` returns a _new_ handle to the specified process.  It is entirely reasonable that the value is different.  In fact, I'd be surprised if it returned the same value.

Comment: @theB if you run the example and even the code in the below answer, then you should know what processes you cannot open. I have nearly 140 processes, almost them are unable to be openned by OpenProcess to return different handles, so I should still post a list of about 140 processes on here? If possible you can now try solving the problem on your side first before trying to solve it on my side.

Comment: I did try it on my side.  It worked exactly as I expected.

Comment: @theB OK, I did not know about system reusing handle (making many confusions to me).

Comment: @Hopeless Can I ask you to reconsider your attitude to providing [mcve] in the future. Being able to copy/paste/compile/run is massively important to answerers. As an asker its in your interest too. You'll get better help. Askers are clear what the code really is. It made all the difference here seeing the real code and we didn't even get to an MCVE. What's more the act of cutting code down to be minimal often isolates the issue for you the asker. It's a great debugging tool. We know what we are doing.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I consider what is enough by myself. I don't even need to read that link. Almost questions of mine are fairly good and enough for the answerer to reproduce it. You in fact did not even need to try my code. You also did not even suggest anything so that I could think of what's wrong. What you said just made me much more confused. Did you even think that I also supposed the code here is enough? And finally you were lucky in this question. I've ***very very rarely*** posted missing-info questions like this.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan if you could have just said something like this: Be careful when using `GetLastWin32Error`, just use it when the function is surely failed by checking its return value. I would have been more thankful to that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan just look at your first comment about `hwnd`. You did not need to make that so confusing. A comment like this would be much more helpful: `hwnd is usually used as name of a variable holding a window handle, not a process handle`.

Comment: *Be careful when using GetLastWin32Error, just use it when the function is surely failed by checing its return value* I did, in the end, say exactly that. But to begin with I could not see your code to call GLW32E. And so could not critique it. I like to help. Where I can. And your comments above suggested that you don't believe that MCVE is useful, and now you saw you have not and will not read this link: [MCVE]. That's up to you clearly. But I think you are missing an opportunity to learn.

Comment: Regarding the hwnd comment, remember that I don't know what's in your mind. Also know that a very common mistake that we see here as answerers is an asker that thinks that a process handle and a window handle are the same thing. You might not have made that mistake, but I did not know what was in your mind. I've seen `hwnd = OpenProcess(...)` many times from people that then go on to do things like `SendMessage(hwnd, ...)` and wonder why nothing happens.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Anyway I believe you still could make it less confusing about that comment. This ***This seems perfectly normal*** should even have not been posted. That kind of confirmation indicated that you surely knew what's wrong. But now you said you did not know what's in my mind at that moment. So weird indeed.

Comment: Actually no, I did not know the real problem when I wrote that first comment. I took you at your word that OpenProcess was failing. Only much later did I realise that was not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error checking is broken. Success is indicated by `OpenProcess` returning a non-zero value. The error code is only meaningful if `OpenProcess` fails, that is if `OpenProcess` returns zero.

So, you must only ask for the error code when the function call fails, as indicated by its return value. You check the error code without checking the return value, which is a mistake. Your code should be more like this:

```
foreach (var proc in Process.GetProcesses())
{
    var procHandle = OpenProcess(ProcessAccessFlags.QueryInformation | ProcessAccessFlags.VirtualMemoryOperation, false, proc.Id);
    if (procHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        // api call failed, can read error code
        var eCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    }
    else
    {
        // api call succeeded, do stuff with handle
        CloseHandle(procHandle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well now it's actually close to what I tried. And actually I've just tried it again this exact code, the return value of `OpenProcess` is almost not IntPtr.Zero (you can read some comments I posted under my question about this). Just in some 2-3 last loops, it returns `0` but sometimes it does not. You can try the code to see it in action. BTW my current app target is a 32 bit.

Comment: No. The code here is very different from the code in the question. Surely you can see that.

Comment: It's different but I tried this before and now I tried it again. Currently no result is printed (I tried printing the `eCode`) because `procHandle` is never `IntPtr.Zero`. You should try it yourself. `OpenProcess` may also be buggy as a guy experienced this and posted here in the second comment https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: When `OpenProcess` returns a non-zero value it has succeeded.

Comment: that should be true but when I print the `procHandle`, all **one** same value is printed. That's what making I think it must be failed.

Comment: The system is just reusing the handle.  Once you call `CloseHandle` windows is free to re-use that handle.

Comment: No. That's not a valid conclusion. The system is re-using the handle.  Remove the call to CloseHandle and you'll see a different number each time. I repeat, OpenProcess succeeds if it returns a non zero value.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan **The system is re-using the handle** this is the most valuable info which should be added to your answer. I did not know about that and that's why I thought it failed before trying to use `GetLastWin32Error` to check it.

Comment: Well, there's been a lot of confusion here, and the information needed to add that can only be found in comments to my answer. The key point is that OpenProcess indicates success by returning a non zero value. That's the key.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan that key may be doubted after searching around via Google and finding some guy talking about some exception (as in the link I posted). So I did not believe that is true.

Comment: @Hopeless: that only happens if you pass in an invalid PID, i.e., one that isn't a multiple of 4.  That's not a bug in Windows, that's programmer error.